# xilinx xps using command line mode

Tags: build, verilog, xilinx

I am currently working with the Xilinx Platform Studio(XPS) tool to make an automated design with command line tools (without using GUI). I know how to build project using XPS in GUI mode, but don't know how to build a project with command line tools. I got some information about the command line tools usage from the "*Embedded System Tools Reference Manual*" and the "*Command Line Tools User Guide*".

But, I didn't get any information about following things:

1. How to select Bus interconnect type.
2. How to select Clock
3. How to select processor
4. How to select BRAM memory
5. How to make signals external
6. How to import our peripheral
7. How to select address

I did all the following steps in XPS command line

1. Creating a new .xmp project
2. Adding architecture, device, package speed
3. Language setting,simulation setting
4. loading ucf file

I don't know how to add peripheral, processor and interconnect bus type.

I am struggling at this stage only - I know how to synthesize, implementation, and Bitfile generation.

If anybody knows information about these things using command line tools or any documents, Kindly reply to this post

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I do not know how to do this in XPS, but with Vivado all of these actions may be done via [Tcl commands](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_4/ug835-vivado-tcl-commands.pdf). Vivado works so much better than XPS. Unfortunately, Vivado does not support older Xilinx devices, so this may not be an option for you.